# Android DefaultHTTPConnection with Keep-Alive does not reuse TCP connection

Tags: android, http, post, connection, keep-alive

I am trying to reuse HTTP connections with Keep Alive. The server supports Keep Alive, I send the Connection: Keep-Alive HTTP headers and still the connection is FIN (initiated by the Android client) right after the response is received. Some help would be appreciated.

Here some code:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
client.setKeepAliveStrategy(new DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy());
client.setReuseStrategy(new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy());
HttpParams params = client.getParams();

ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
post.setHeader("Connection","Keep-Alive");
ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(requestBundle.postString().getBytes());
entity.setContentType("application/xml");
post.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

When I check the HTTP request headers I see these:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
Content-Length: 459\r\n
Content-Type: application/xml\r\n
Host: xxx.yyy.com\r\n
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)\r\n
```

In the HTTP response headers I see these:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Content-Type: application/xml\r\n
Content-Length: 8049\r\n
Date: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 03:14:40 GMT\r\n
Server: lighttpd/1.4.31\r\n
```

Looking at the responses and other TCP packets going over the line, it is clear that the Android client initiates a FIN based on some HTTP client settings that I am not aware of, which are not caused by the Keep-Alive settings on the server (the HTTP response does not contain header "Connection: close").

Please enlighten me!

Cheers,
Andrej

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Facing similar problem.

Comment: How do you check the HTTP headers? If you are checking it from the code, the system may add additional headers later. The best would be looking at the headers with some external sniffer. Maybe this example can help: http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/528e1f38da0a15d2a9785e59/org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient?tag=bumblebee

Comment: @MichaelGopshtein try `stetho` library on android, it will allow you to debug app network from chrome instruments